# Formatting Play Store review text

Tags: google-play-store

I wrote a fairly long review with 4-5 paragraphs, but when posted the Play store seems to strip out all the newlines and just have a giant wall of text instead. I also tried using simple html (just the `<p>` paragraph tags) which did not work either.

Can the review text be formatted, and if so how? I wish HTML or BBcode was supported, but that's certainly not the case - still, maybe there is some conventions to get basic formatting in?

Comment: You need to use <br /> for line break (note space)

Accepted answer here [Google Play app description formatting]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071127/google-play-app-description-formatting) shows how to format app description and it works for reviews too.

Comment: Yesterday, when I posted the review, it was working as described . 

Surprisingly, the formatting was reverted by Play Store today. Maybe it runs a periodic check and removes formatting.  Hence, deleted the answer